# Storing arrays in Solr

Tags: solr

How can one store an array of values in a Solr index? I am specifically trying to formulate a schema.xml file.

Consider the following potential Solr document:

```
ID: 351
Name: Beatles
Members:
    1) Name: John
       Instrument: Guitar
    2) Name: Paul
       Instrument: Guitar
    3) Name: George
       Instrument: Bass
    4) Name: Ringo
       Instrument: Drums
```

In MySQL I would have three tables, like so:

```
Bands:
    BandID
    Name
People:
    PersonID
    Name
    Instrument
BandsPeople:
    BandID references Bands(BandID)
    PersonID references People(PersonID)
```

**Disregarding the concept that a person could belong to multiple bands and other advantages of the MySQL approach, my goal is to learn how to store arrays in Solr. The band is simply an example and possibly not a good one at that!**

The obvious approach for having multiple `Member`s would be a multiValued field:

```
<field name="member" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

However, that multiValued field itself needs to have subvalues. I do not see any documentation on how to formulate the schema. Note that I am using Solr 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple answers, but sadly none of them use `multivalued`.

- Leverage lucene's nested documents (could be mal-performant)
- Heavily denormalize the documents with a document per each option. Then use Lucene's Grouping feature. (This is the 'SOLR/Lucene Way'.)
- Follow the span query and term vector with offsets advice @ the following blog:
  http://blog.griddynamics.com/2011/06/solr-experience-search-parent-child.html
  http://blog.griddynamics.com/2011/07/solr-experience-search-parent-child.html
  http://blog.griddynamics.com/2011/10/solr-experience-search-parent-child.html
- Create indexed facet names.

For indexed facet names, your data (one document) would look like this:

```
id="351" band="Beatles" 
   member_0="John" instrument_0="Guitar" 
   member_1="Paul" instrument_1="Guitar" 
   ...
```

With relatively short lists (shorter than hundreds), the latter is the easiest on your document size and complexity, but forces the issue into the client's lap as far as searching.

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel. I'm not sure that the dynamic field approach is a good approach, though I do agree that there are not many other approaches to choose from. I'll play around with this, thanks!

Comment: I'm of the opinion we've been given *no* "good" approach. Just choose the one that's the most compatible with your environment. (Or don't do it.)

Comment: Right, this obviously was not a use-case that Lucene (or Solr) was designed for. The blog in the edited links is terrific, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Lucene already has joining so you could aproximate the db schema with them with some caveats, see [Grouping and Joining in Lucene/Solr](http://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/grouping-and-joining-in-lucenesolr). Solr will eventually get accesss to that as well, check [ongoing work](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3076)

Comment: Thank you, but as stated my intention is to learn how to store an array in Solr, not how to approximate the database which was given as an example. +1 anyway for the information regarding Lucene, though. Thanks.